# Importing Modules - How Much is Too Much?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

As a newbie, I've grown fond of importing modules almost by default when I start writing something just because I call on certain functions within them quite a bit (modules like random, time, os, and sys).  However, does this impact performance at all?  If I only want a specific function in the module, am I better served by asking for it explicitly or should I not care?

Answer (score 9):

When you do `from module import name`, Python still has to run `module`, so there is no difference performance-wise.

Generally, if you are only using one thing from a module, the using `from x import y` is fine, but otherwise, using `import x` and then `x.y` results in a lower chance of conflicting names.

The reason for this is that Python doesn't treat functions and classes specially. When you import from a module, all you are doing is taking objects from that module and using them. This is useful, as it makes modules (as well as classes and functions) extremely flexible, but it does mean that Python has to run the whole script for a module before it can import from it (naturally, module writers can work around this by using the `if name == "main":` idiom to insert code that shouldn't be run on import).

Comment: What if I use "from module import *"     ?

Comment: @Kimomaru That's generally a bad idea, unless the module was specifically designed for it. In most cases, it just pollutes your namespace and makes it harder to work with the code. Naturally, it still loads the whole module as the other methods do.

Comment: Interesting.  So, it's better to be as specific as I can be because it will keep things organized.  I can imagine importing everything, then accidentally creating a function named identically to something imported - would cause a problem.

Comment: @Kimomaru Essentially, yes. Not to mention one module could have something with the same name as another module. People often accidentally call a variable `list` for example, and then get into trouble when they try to use the `list()` built-in later. The more you import into the namespace, the more issues like this are likely to crop up.

Comment: Very interesting.  Okay, will make note.  Thanks, Lattyware.

Comment: @Kimomaru: you can also find a reference at the end of the "imports" section of the [PEP8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports): Wildcard imports (from <module> import *) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools. There is one defensible use case for a wildcard import, which is to republish an internal interface as part of a public API.